# Issue while creating IBM MobileFirst image on IBM Container

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, containers, ibm-cloud

We are trying to create IBM MobileFirst Container for bluemix by following the MobileFirst containers tutorial in : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/administrators/7.1/bluemix/

As per the tutorial/video we have created the MobileFirst Analytic server and trying to create MobileFirst server image using prepareserver.sh script in which it gives me an error saying that repository/tag is not valid.

[image]

I tried creating the image using Dockerfile still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: what is your namespace? you can check with this command: `cf ic namespace get`. Also, please add the full command and error output in your question as a text, it would be much more clear than this cropped image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the capital letters in your image name. The repository part of your image name (in your case, `MobiGOVServer`) must contain only lowercase letters, digits, and separators.

The tag (in your case, `latest`) is the only part of the image name where capital letters are allowed.

For more information, see the [docker tag reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/).

Please retry your build with a lowercase image name.

Comment: Thanks Michael, It worked with lowercase image name.

Answer (score 0):

@srujan reddy - one of 2 things is happening. The namespace registry.ng.bluemix.net/parthotechnologies does not exist. Or you don't have access to it.

run cf target and :

1. Check if you have logged in to the *API Endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net* . (Accidentally you might have logged in to https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net )
2. Check you have logged in to the correct Org. The registry namespace is unique to an org.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your response.